# Constructing point at corner of layer extent using QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I’m in the Modeler. My input is a polygon layer with a polygon (agricultural field) and a line layer with a line indicating a direction of travel within the field.
The field will be filled with parallel lines, but the main issue is to place the first line  at the right distance from the most extreme part of the field.

I guess I need to find one of the corners of the polygon layer extents, and relatively to that point create a point from which I will construct a line with the same length as the polygon and the same azimuth as the input line.

How do I make a point in, for example, the south/west corner of the layer extent, using the Modeler?

I guess I will be using the “geometry from expression” tool, but I don’t know the expressions